# Mobile device detection and redirect node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile

I need to redirect according to user-agent in my Node.js application. My app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var models = require('./models');
var EventEmitterService = require('./services/EventEmitterService');

//..... ommited

var io = require('socket.io');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = io.listen(server);
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('port', Settings.WEBSERVICE.APP_PORT);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) { //!! WORKING, BUT NOT AS NEED
    var ua = req.header('user-agent');
    // Check the user-agent string to identyfy the device. 
    if (/mobile|iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|opera|mini|windows\sce|palm|smartphone|iemobile|ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle/i.test(ua)) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + 'public/app/index.html');
    } else {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + 'mobile/app/index.html');
    }
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/app'))); //!! OR mobile/app according to user-agent

app.use('/', MainController);
app.use('/schedule', ScheduleController);
//.... ommited

models.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
    TaskService.clearTasks().then(function () {
        server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
            MessageService.listen(io);

            var now = moment();
            var formatted = now.format('HH:mm:ss Z')
            console.log("CURRENT TIME" + formatted)

            process.on("uncaughtException", function (error) {
                console.log("uncaughtException invoked: " + error);
            });

            process.on("unhandledRejection", function (reason) {
                console.log("unhandledRejection invoked: " + reason);
            });

            EventEmitterService.logInvoke('INFO', 'Removing old tasks');
            EventEmitterService.start().then(function () {
                InitService.initialize();
            });
        }).on('error', function (e) {

        });
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can add a property `myAppPath` to the `req` and use it in your application:

```
// appPath middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var ua = req.headers['user-agent'].toLowerCase();

    // Check the user-agent string to identify the device 
    req.myAppPath = (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(ua) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(ua.substr(0, 4))) ?
        'mobile/app' :
        'public/app';

    next();
});
```

Comment: Method is correct, but site type (desktop or mobile) determines in this line:
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/app')));`

Comment: Changed the solution.. Hope it helps